# Configure Qt Creator to use Boost on Windows

Tags: qt, boost, qt-creator

I want to use boost with C++ in Qt Creator on Windows.
I followed the instructions from:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

So I ran `.\bootstrap.bat` then `./b2 install --prefix=C:\Boost` then I added `C:\Boost\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

I want to make Qt Creator "see" boost now and I couldn't find any resources on the web. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: When you say "I want to use boost", do you mean "I want to use Boost Build" or "I want to use the Boost C++ Library"?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a starter and didn't use boost before, I only know it's a C++ library. What I want is to use the library in my C++ code.
So I suppose that Boost Build and Boost C++ Library are different things, what are them and what is the difference between them?
Thank you for the comment

Comment: Even knowing what boost is and having dealt with building it properly (with desired proerties) before is no guarantee, you'll spend half a night messing with its building and integration into the IDE. So beware :)

Comment: @HorgaIuliu  Boost Build is a C++ build system (which is what you linked to in your question).  If you're using Qt Creator, you're likely using qmake or cmake right now.  It doesn't sound like you want to change this.  The Boost C++ library (www.boost.org) is a fairly large C++ library (and has some overlap with Qt).  Download it and follow the usage instructions -- if you're still having problems, leave a comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I finally managed to compile a couple of the Boost Filesystem examples found at [Boost Filesystem tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html) with in Windows 7 with Qt Creator 2.7.1, Qt 4.8.4 and Boost 1.54. Here is my qmake project file.

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/include/boost-1_54
    LIBS += -LC:/boost/lib \
            -lboost_serialization-mgw46-mt-d-1_54 \
            -lboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-d-1_54 \
            -lboost_system-mgw46-mt-d-1_54
}
```

Please note the usage of "/" instead of "\".

My Boost library was compiled to the "c:\boost" directory using MinGW.

Comment: win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/User/Downloads/dev/boost_1_61_0
    LIBS += "-LC:/dev/Boost/lib/" \
 "-Llibboost_filesystem-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a", "-Llibboost_system-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a", "-Llibboost_serialization-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a" -LLIBS

}

Answer (score 3):

I will answer this question based on other answers I found.

First, you need to use boost libraries compiled with the same compiler used by QtCreator (usually mingw). If you use prebuilt boost libraries (usually compiled using msvc), libraries will link but undefined reference error will occur.

So, you need to compile boost libraries by yourself. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Add the mingw binaries to PATH. Go to `Control panel > System > Advanced settings > Environmet variables` and set the `path` variable. In my case, the value was `c:\Qt\Tools\mingw\bin`.
2. Open a terminal and go to the directory in which boost was decompressed. Run this: `bootstrap.bat gcc`
3. Now run this: `b2 link=shared toolset=gcc`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got yourself confused a little bit.

The link you've mentioned is for the Boost Build system, not for the Boost libraries. [There's a full installer on www.boostpro.com](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) for the library files, that'll get you up and running a bit faster, however if that's not working properly there's a guide [here](http://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/) on building it yourself.

Next step after you've got them built is to make Qt aware of them. You generally do this on a per project basis, either by adjusting the settings through Qt Creator or by directly editing the `.pro` file for your project. I prefer editing the `.pro` as it's how I learnt, if you go down that route you need to let it know the `INCLUDEPATH` for the header files and the `LIBS` path for the libraries. A lot of Boost is header file only, so depending what parts you use you may or may not need the `LIBS` part.