# How to use boost with QtCreator

Tags: c++, boost, windows-10, qt-creator

I had a running C++ project in QtCreator and wanted to use some features of boost. I downloaded the boost zip file from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

But I guess I have to do some steps so that it gets picked up by QtCreator, Currently, if I type #include <boost/process.hpp> in the file it says `file not found` error. What steps should be taken to make this work?

Comment: Did you try to search for similar threads before asking your question ? Because I just typed "boost with QtCreator" in google and the first result was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113679/configure-qt-creator-to-use-boost-on-windows/17795006)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure Qt Creator to use Boost on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113679/configure-qt-creator-to-use-boost-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide a path to the header file while compiling.
If you are using Qt with qmake add the path like this inside the .pro file

```sh
HEADERS += \
{path to the header}

SOURCES += \
{path to the source file}
```

if you are using Qt with CMake you can easily add your header file like this in your CMakeList.txt file

```sh
include_directories(${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```